# Creating indexed nodes on neo4j cypher via rest api

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm trying to create an indexed node in cypher, with the following syntax:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ start m=node:person(UID= "1")  return m;
==> +------------+
==> | m          |
==> +------------+
==> | Node[64]{} |
==> +------------+
==> 1 row
==> 0 ms
==> 
neo4j-sh (?)$ start n = node(64) return n.UID;
==> EntityNotFoundException: The property 'UID' does not exist on Node[64]
```

Why is it that the node appears to be created, but the property I'm creating, and that seems to be successfully returned, does not exist?

Is there an easier way?  I used to use py2neo's function:

```
neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/").get_or_create_indexed_node(index='person', key='UID', value=self.id, properties={'UID' : self.id})
```

But this appears to have been deprecated---it no longer works with the latest version of py2neo, which does not appear to support the `properties` argument any longer (and for future folks, `index` is replaced with `index_name`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index and a property are two different things.

It seems you have a node in your graph with an index named `person` and key/value pair UID:"1". Your first query gets your node by its index. But the index is not a property of the node. You can fire up the webadmin to visualize how the indices are managed in your graph.

As far as i know there is nothing in the documentation on how to create indices with cypher, but you can easily use the REST API to manipulate them ([link](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-indexes.html)).

Comment: Isn't the index "person," as given by `start n node:/person/`?  The properties are defined in parens after.  Py2neo uses the REST API under the hood to have created the index.

Comment: Yes, the above query uses the index named person looking up the key/value pair UID:"1". While in practice the key/value pairs are often created to reflect node properties this is not necessary as far as i know. If you look at the REST index documentation (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-indexes.html) you can easily create key/value indices that have nothing to do with the nodes properties.

Comment: I think I don't understand---are you saying my syntax is not creating a key/value on an index, or not creating a node at all, or not creating a property on an indexed node?

Comment: I mean the cypher statement is just a query. What you want to do is CREATE UNIQUE (http://assets.neo4j.org/download/Neo4j_CheatSheet_v3.pdf), but i dont know if you can index nodes at all with cypher (unless auto indexing).

Answer (score 1):

The method has not been deprecated and the `properties` argument is still valid, as before. The only change, as you identify, is the change from `index` to `index_name` for the first argument.

The documentation is here:

http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/graphs_nodes_relationships.html#py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService.get_or_create_indexed_node

Note that the `properties` will only actually be used when the node does not already exist, i.e. when doing a 'create' but not when doing a 'get'. Otherwise, the existing node will remain as-is.